# Distributing points on a sphere

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory, spheres

The following question comes from a statement in Joshua Greene's proof of the Kneser conjecture.

He states that, given $n$ and $k$ positive integers, we can find $2n+k$ points on $S^{k+1}$ such that no $k+2$ points of these points lie on a great $k$-sphere.

Why is this true?

Comment: what is a great $k$-sphere? the ones that have radius equal to the radius of the original sphere?

Comment: It is a subset of $S^{k+1} \subset \mathbb{R}^{k+2}$ obtained by taking one of the coordinates $x_1, \ldots, x_{k+2} to be zero.

Comment: I don't think that is correct, otherwise it would be trivial.

Comment: Oh, right—the actual definition is the subset obtained by intersecting a hyperplane through the origin with our sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great $k$-sphere is the intersection of $S^{k+1}$ (as a subset of $\mathbb R^{k+2}$) with a $(k+1)$-dimensional hyperplane through the origin.
Such a hyperplane is determined by $k+1$ linearly independent points.

Just start out with $k+1$ linearly independent points, and repeatedly add
a point that is not on any of the hyperplanes determined by any $k+1$ of the
points already present (always possible, since a finite union of hyperplanes will not cover the whole sphere).

Comment: Nice :)${}{}{}{}$